# Does the Limes superior exists for unbounded series?

Tags: analysis

If $(a_n) \subset \mathbb{R}$ has an upper bound but not a lower bound, does then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sup a_n$ exists in general?

For example: $a_n=-n$ then $a_n$ is upper bounded by $-1$ but not lower bounded and
$\lim \sup a_n=\lim -n=- \infty.$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Completeness Axiom asserts that any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is bounded from above (resp. below) has a least upper bound (resp. greatest lower bound). Recall that $\limsup$ is defined by:
$$
\limsup_{n\to \infty} (a_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sup_{m \geq n} a_m),
$$
and for $n \to \infty$, $\sup_{m \geq n} a_m$ is non-increasing.

Answer (score 0):

We can consider $\limsup_{n\to \infty} (a_n) $ as $\sup$ of $(a_n)$'s limit points and so is defined for any sequence. In unbound case it will be some $\infty$. For you question we can consider $a_{2n} = -n, a_{2n+1} = 1$, so it have not lower bound, have upper bound and have $\limsup_{n\to \infty} (a_n) =1$

Comment: But if we consider $a_n=-n$ then $a_n$ also have an upper bound ($-1$) but $\lim \sup a_n= - \infty$

Comment: Yes, it's correct, because in this case it have only one limit point. We can even say, that it converged to $-\infty$ so it is limit point. I brought example when $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sup a_n$ is finite.